# Evaluate $\int\frac{dx}{x^3+1}$ without using partial Fractions

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

Evaluate $$I=\int\frac{dx}{x^3+1}$$ without using partial Fractions

I tried in this way:

$$I=\int \frac{\frac{xdx}{x^4}}{1+\frac{1}{x^3}}$$

Put $1+\frac{1}{x^3}=t$

$$I=\frac{-1}{3}\int \frac{dt}{t(t-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

Any way to help me?

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Write the integrand as

$$\frac {1}{x^3+1}=1-\frac {x}{3}\frac{3x^2}{x^3+1}$$

and integrate by parts.

Comment: Funny forbidding playing with fractions inside the integral but allowing it elsewhere...lol...These are weird rule or is it kafka's integral...No fractions play inside..but outside it's permitted....whatever you do you break the rules

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it, you can do the following. This is really just a sketch, there are lots of fine details omitted.

Write

$$\int \frac{1}{x^3+1} dx = \int 1 - \frac{x^3}{x^3+1} dx = x - \frac{1}{3} \int x \frac{3x^2}{x^3+1} dx.$$

This second term can be integrated by parts: take $u=x,dv=\frac{3x^2}{x^3+1}$. The boundary term gives a contribution to the integral and leaves you to evaluate $\int \ln(x^3+1) dx$. This can be split into $\ln(x+1) + \ln(x^2-x+1)$. The first term is easy to integrate by parts. The second term is $\ln((x-1/2)^2+3/4)$. Upon a suitable change of variable and factoring out constants, it becomes enough to compute $\int \ln(x^2+1) dx$. This can be done by integrating by parts the opposite of how we did before: $dv=dx,u=\ln(x^2+1)$ forces us to evaluate $\int x \frac{2x}{x^2+1} dx$, but this is now easy after a long division.

This is *way* harder than doing it by partial fractions, basically because you wound up doing partial fractions implicitly anyway, but obfuscated by two integration by parts steps.